# Separating Delimited Variable into array elements in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, variables, delimiter

I long variable in vb.net which contains the following information,

```
Dim g As String = "$C:\Program Files\Cavaj Java Decompiler\cavaj.exe$C:\Users\Yoosuf\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe$C:\Program Files\DVD Maker\dvdmaker.exe$C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS2\ImageReady.exe$C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaws.exe$"
```

The `$` symbol is used as a delimiter to separate each item from the other. I need to add the exe file name at the end of each path to a listbox. However the initial process of retrieving the variable to individual array elements is not working properly.

```
Dim strArr() As String = g.Split("$")  'This variable is empty
For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
Dim arr As String = strArr(count).Split("\")

Dim strval As String = ""
For i As Integer = 3 To arr.Length - 1
        strval = arr(i)
        Dim j As Integer = arr.Length - 1
        strval = arr(j)
        Dim result As String = strval.Substring(g.Length - 5)
        result = g.Substring(g.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(result)
 Next
Next
```

Comment: Works fine for me. strArr.Length = 7. I can't see any problem with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the code below and the associated comments. Also I have comment out some code which I feel is not required based on what you want to do.

```
Dim strArr() As String = g.Split("$")  'This variable is empty
        For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
            Dim arr() As String = strArr(count).Split("\") ' Split returns an array

            Dim strval As String = ""
            For i As Integer = 3 To arr.Length - 1
                'strval = arr(i)
                Dim j As Integer = arr.Length - 1
                strval = arr(j)
                'Dim result As String = strval.Substring(g.Length - 5)
                'result = g.Substring(g.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(strval)
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to do all this work. The **[System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)** class has methods to do this for you. You want to use either **[System.IO.Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)** or **[System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)**. Since you've already split all the file paths, just pass those paths to either of the aforementioned methods and add the result to your listbox.

```
Dim strArr() As String = g.Split("$")
For Each path As String In strArr
    ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path))
Next
```